# How do I create dependencies between tasks in Asana using the API?

Tags: asana, asana-api

We're excited about the dependencies in Asana (https://asana.com/guide/help/tasks/dependencies), however can't figure out how to access dependencies using the API.   It appears that marking a task as dependent on another task is only via the GUI.   Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't have dependency management in our API at this point. We are always evaluating when the best time to implement these sorts of features are, though, so thanks for reaching out - I've recorded this question as another vote for dependency management. Although I don't have a concrete timetable for when we might get to this, we have identified it as a good opportunity to work on within the next few months, so hopefully you'll see dependency support happen sooner rather than later!